# How can i query uri for the song from the internal memory

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-file

I want to access song details including `artist`, `album`, `duration`, `title`, `display name`, etc.

This can be done by querying `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for files in external storage, but I can't query the files from internal storage using `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

I have been stuck on this for last two days. Here is my code:

```
void loadPlayList(){
    ArrayList<Song> list = null;
    try{
        list = new ArrayList<Song>();
        Uri uri;
       //if(SplashScreen.getDirPrefs())
            uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
       //else
       //Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] m_data = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
        Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, m_data, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"=1", null, null);

        PlayerManager pm = new PlayerManager();

        //Log.e("vmplayer loadPlayList ", "cursor : "+c.getCount());
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())//while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            String str = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            str = str.substring(0, (str.length() - 4));

            for(int i = 0; i < GlobalClass.songList.size(); i++)
            {
                Song sn = GlobalClass.songList.get(i);
                //Log.e("vmplayer loadPlayList ", "str : "+str);
                if(sn.name.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
                {
                    sn.title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                    sn.album = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                    sn.albumId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                    sn.artist = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    sn.duration = pm.milliSecondsToTimer((long)(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))));
                    //Log.e("vmplayer loadPlayList ", "dur : "+sn.duration);
                    Bitmap art = null;
                    try{
                        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
                        Uri albumUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentUri,c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)));

                        ContentResolver res = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                        InputStream in = res.openInputStream(albumUri);
                        art = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        //art = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),albumUri);
                        //art = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(art, 100, 100, true);
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                        Log.e("vmplayer loadPlayList ", "err1 :"+e);
                        art = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.artwork);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("vmplayer loadPlayList err2", ""+e);
                        art = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.artwork);
                    }

                    //Log.e("vmplayer loadPlayList art", "bit map : "+art);
                    sn.coverImg = art;
                    list.add(sn);
                }
            }
        }

        GlobalClass.songList.clear();
        GlobalClass.songList = list;
        Log.e("loadPlayList", "cont : "+GlobalClass.songList.size());
        c.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("vmplayer loadPlayList err", ""+e);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: it should work I personally tried that it works INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI please check the code again

Comment: if it doesn't work provide the WRITE and READ Permissions. I have never used permission. It worked with me without providing it. But just give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is caused by your Android version.

I wrote the same code as yours. It worked on Android 5.0.1, but crashed on Android 2.3.6. I think that you should try another method to query in internal storage if your Android version is too old.

Comment: I tried my another android device which is 2.3.6. But the App worked on it. Maybe just the problem of the device. Or the OS has been modified so that you are unable to open the database in internal storage. By the way, I can pull the database from the phone which the app failed on. And I can open the database by SQLite Expert. The database exists.